# C# generic return with generic type set in the method not in the call

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to setup a method that retrieves data from a database, and based on data in there it will create and hydrate a class with a generic component.

```
public class MyObject<T> where T : BaseMyType 
{
    T MyTypedObject { get; set; }
}
public class MyType1 : BaseMyType 
{
    string Key { get; set; }
}
public class MyType2 : BaseMyType 
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public MyObject<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : BaseMyType
{
    if(Situation1)
        return new MyObject(MyType1);
    else
        return new MyObject(MyType2);
}
```

This code complains that MyObject<MyType1> cannot be converted to MyObject<T>.  Now I need to use it like this:

```
var myObject = MyMethod();
```

The call of course complains it cannot infer the type from the usage.  I understand the compiler error messages, I just am not sure how to do what I need.

Comment: Given that none of this is known at compile time, you shouldn't be using generics at all.  It's not going to help you; it'll just get in your way.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on a better approach to it?  Everywhere except data loading has the approach being perfect for our needs, I just have not figured out how to get this one piece done.

Comment: Why do you need generics? Interfaces may be enough

Comment: @JonHelms Just strip out all of the generics.  You're not using the generic type in the implementation of the method, nor when calling it; there's literally nothing that benefits from having this be generic, and all of those places would need to be re-written to use reflection in order to actually use generics.

Comment: The objects all have several properties on them, but the generic'd objects do not have the same properties on them so MyType1 and MyType2 do not share the same signature.  I have added some extra code, I tried to keep the code short but I may have been too brief.

Comment: @JonHelms Which is why you're not able to statically bind the objects to their members, which means not using generics.

Comment: Start off your design by just using `object` and then review which problems that causes.

Comment: I think if you don't want to provide the type at compile time, then you should use the `dynamic` keyword. Like return `List<dynamic>` etc. Generics are used in scenarios where you provide the type at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done, but…let's suppose for a moment that we could figure out a way for the following statement to compile in the way that you want:

```
var myObject = MyMethod();
```

Then what is the code using `myObject` going to look like? In this hypothetical scenario, the variable `myObject` will sometimes have the type `MyType1` and sometime have the type `MyType2`. Will the code using `myObject` care about that?

If all that code will do is use members of the shared base type (i.e. `BaseMyType`), then the fix is easy. Just forget about the generic approach:

```
public BaseMyType MyMethod()
{
    if(Situation1)
        return new MyType1();
    else
        return new MyType2();
}
```

If it *does* care about the differences (i.e. needs to access either `Key` or `Id` depending on the type that was returned), then even if you could do the impossible, the calling code is still going to need to conditionally handle the individual scenarios based on the `Situation1` variable. Which would mean that you put the check for `Situation1` in the wrong place.

Instead, your caller should look more like this:

```
if (Situation1)
{
    MyType1 myObject = MyMethod1();

    // do situation 1 stuff
}
else
{
    MyType2 myObject = MyMethod2();

    // do situation 2 stuff
}
```

Where the implementation of your original `MyMethod()` has been split into two methods, `MyMethod1()` and `MyMethod2()`, corresponding to the two scenarios. Again, note the complete lack of generics as part of the implementation. It's not called for, and won't work.

It's even possible that you need a polymorphic implementation of the caller, i.e. so you don't have to check `Situation1` more than once. But without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be impossible to comment more thoroughly on that possibility.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this is basically what I ended up with.  The key is that the important stuff is virtual methods on the base class, so the parent of the generic is just a carrier.  So I've declared the "starting" method returns as MyObject<MyBase>, and then when it calls MyBase.Validate that goes into the specific type.  Serialization still serializes the actual type, so all is good.  You post was extremely helpful.